# Lightning component event not fired or handled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, nested

To build a [**nested** component structure as detailed here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180212) I have build the solution described in one of the answers which recommended to send an **APPLICATION** event...

**parentInitialized.evt**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object" />
</aura:event>
```

from the parent component

**parent.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="children" type="Object[]" default="[]" />

    <aura:registerEvent name="parentInitialized" type="c:parentInitialized" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:handler name="childInitialized" event="c:childInitialized" action="{!c.registerStep}"/>   
</aura:component>
```

**parentController.js**

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        var evt = $A.get("e.c:parentInitialized");
        evt.fire();
    },

    //FAILS HERE: child component events are never handled here
    registerStep: function(component, event, helper) {
        var children = component.get("v.children");
        children.push({ "data": event.getParam("data")});
        component.set("v.children", children);
    }
})
```

...to tell the nested child components to register themselves using a bubbling **COMPONENT event**

**childInitialized.evt**

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object" />
</aura:event>
```

**child.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="position" type="Integer" required="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="title" type="String" required="true" />

    <aura:registerEvent name="childInitialized" type="c:childInitialized" /> 

    <aura:handler event="c:parentInitialized" action="{!c.registerWithParent}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**childController.js**

```
({
    registerWithParent: function(component, event, helper) {
        var evt = component.getEvent("childInitialized");
        evt.setParams({
            "data": component.get("v.position")
        });
        evt.fire();
    }
})
```

But this never happens. The parent sends the Application event which is received by a child components. The also fire their component event. At least I see no errors.

**But it is never received by `parentController.js` `registerWithParent()` method. Why??**

*Note: The Lightning Inspector didn't run for strange reasons on this page in my Chrome so I could not see if the events where fired and just not handled or not even fired*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use the pattern of:

```
<c:parent>
   <c:child name="xyz" />
</c:parent>
```

Then you must use `includeFacets="true"` to make a component event from the child bubble to the parent in the way you think it would in a DOM i.e.

```
<aura:handler name="childInitialized" event="c:childInitialized" action="{!c.registerStep}" includeFacets="true"/>
```

This worked for me with component events, but Robert informs me that to make it work with his application event, he also required `phase="bubble"` i.e.

```
<aura:handler name="childInitialized" event="c:childInitialized" action="{!c.registerStep}" includeFacets="true" phase="bubble"/>
```

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_bubbling.htm

This cost me a lot of time a few weeks ago! Grr!

Comment: You save my week... great! For some reasons that I don't fully understand I also had to add phase="bubble". Maybe you can add that to your answer.

Comment: Are you also using Application events from Parent to child? How can I ensure that only the correct parents talk to their children. Add aura:id of parent to app event payload ?? Any idea?

Comment: @RobertSösemann I was using this for pretty much the same scenario as you (child to parent communication), and I was using a component event. Unless there's some other reason to do so, component event seems better. In my application, I just used event.getSource() in the handler.

Comment: for parent to child you can use aura:methods. you can expose a method from the child component using aura:method and then in the child component declaration in parent give an aura:id. using the aura:id you can invoke the child component method.

Comment: @RedDevil: For the parent to call a method of the children the parent would have to know them. But I want them to be loosely coupled. Passing aura:ids would "kill" that design decision.

Comment: @Aidan are you sure that I can replace the event that tells the children that the parent has initialized from APPLICATION to COMPONENT? I thought the later on bubble up in the hierarchy. What did you use event.getSource()  for?

Comment: @RobertSösemann you're right - I misunderstood that part of what you're trying to do. Your parent to child communication probably would need to be an application event. It still seems a bit smelly, though, and I don't know enough about your overall goal to suggest an improvement. I was going to write a blog post about inter-component communication (more than the SF-blog one), but I haven't got around to it yet. Will let you know when I do!