# can parent handle Childs event fired by child during init?

Tags: lightning, lightning-events, init

I have a child component

```
<aura:component controller="campingController">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <aura:registerEvent name="add" type="c:enqueueEvent" />
    <lightning:button label="test" onclick="{!c.doInit}"/> 
</aura:component>
```

In its init I am firing a event

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var evt = component.getEvent('add');
        evt.setParams({
            actionobject:''
        });
        evt.fire();
    }
```

Its parent component is handling this event

```
<aura:component >

    <aura:handler name="add" event="c:enqueueEvent" 
        action="{!c.addInQueue}" includeFacets="true"/>
    <c:child/>    
</aura:component>
```

I am not able to handle event in parent that was fired by child on init.

I know that might be due to reason that Child is  initialised first then parent is initialised.

I have gone through [Communication between parent and child Lightning components during initialization](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180212/communication-between-parent-and-child-lightning-components-during-initializatio)
and [Lightning component event not fired or handled](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180539/lightning-component-event-not-fired-or-handled) but firing application event on init of parent is not a workable solution for me.

do we any other workaround?

Comment: I suspect this may be an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I suggest you ask a question that directly asks what you're trying to do, instead of focusing on a solution that may not be optimal or even applicable for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @sfdcfox yes I know I did not provided exactly what problem I am trying to solve. Actually I am currently working on some hobby projects trying to solve problems that I have faced during development.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for x-y problem article.

Comment: @sfdcfox this is what I was working on https://medium.com/@manjotsingh0074/did-a-enqueueaction-action-grouped-your-actions-f33ce710f0e3

Comment: Nifty idea. I haven't had a use for this type of pattern myself, but I'm sure at least a few people have had this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speaking directly to the question at hand, you should definitely wait for the platform to settle before trying to fire events. As such, if you want an event to go off as soon as the platform's ready, set a callback:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    setTimeout($A.getCallback(() => component.getEvent('add')
      .setParams({actionobject:''}).fire()
    ));
}
```

This will get picked up immediately after the rendering cycle finishes, and all components in the hierarchy will be able to respond to events.