# Variable Undefined...But it Really Is

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, javascript-controller

I'm working in a Lightning Aura component, and when I run it in the browser it's saying that my element is undefined.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myElement">
    ...
</div>
```

**Controller.js**

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.myFunction(component, event, helper);
}
```

**Helper.js**

```
myFunction: function(component, event, helper) {
    const myElement = document.getElementById("myElement");
    $A.util.addClass(myElement , "hello-world");
},
```

I've tried a variation by setting `aura:id` on the HTML element...

**HTML**

```
<div aura:id="myElement">
    ...
</div>
```

**Helper.js**

```
myFunction: function(component, event, helper) {
    const myElement = component.find("myElement").getElement();
    $A.util.addClass(myElement , "hello-world");
},
```

But the results are the same: `myFunction` still comes across as undefined.

Comment: The find/aura:id method should work. The one you've posted here will **not** work.

Comment: I updated the above question to show the `aura:id/find` version I'm using which also says my element is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Getting/using native element Id's is typically a bad idea with dynamic content in general. You are on the right track with setting the `aura:id` attribute, and using `component.find()`, but i think you are simply missing the following `getElement()` to get what you are looking for. Try setting your aura:id property again, and grab it in your controller using:

```
myElement = component.find("myElement").getElement();
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and I'm getting the same error, just a variation: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElement' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently calling the method before the first render cycle. The `init` handler runs before the component is rendered. Alternatively, you're modifying an element that causes a re-render and you're not waiting for that cycle to finish. To prove that this should generally work, I wrote this code:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <div aura:id="myElement">
        ...
    </div>
    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.myFunction}" label="Do it!" />
</aura:application>
```

....

```
({
    myFunction: function(component, event, helper) {
        const myElement = component.find("myElement");
        $A.util.addClass(myElement , "hello-world");
    }
})
```

....

```
.THIS.hello-world {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

....

If you put this in to a Lightning Application, you'll see it works. Therefore, this is just a timing issue. Your code *here* is just fine, it's just when you're calling the method that's incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. In my project I won't be using Lightning Application, so I think I'll just need to find a creative way around this. Appreciate you explaining the timing aspect of this.

Comment: @MattSmith A Lightning Component uses the same idea, it's just that an App is a stand-alone component.

Comment: Thanks. It's not specified in my example, but I'm looking in sessionStorage for a value if it's there or not, then firing a method on doInit. It sounds like that's not possible because doInit is firing before the HTML renders.

Comment: @MattSmith Yep. That's the gist of it. By the way, have you looked at my example of a [sessionStorage-backed value provider](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/180019/2984)? It allows you to build something like this fundamentally in your components. Alternatively, you can check the values in `afterRender` in a [Custom Renderer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm).